# Inequality question? If $x \lt y$, prove that $x^2 \lt y^2$

Tags: analysis, inequality

If $x \lt y$

Prove that

$x^2 \lt y^2$

When x and y are real positive numbers

Comment: Note that $y^2-x^2=(y+x)(y-x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply $x<y$ by the positive numbers $x$ and $y$ in turn to get $xx<xy$ and $xy<yy$ so that
$$
xx<xy<yy
$$

Comment: This is the way that I would have done it. Factorising the difference between two squares is fine, but this uses the basic properties of the order more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$$

This is less than $0$, since it is given that $x<y\iff x-y<0$ and $x,y>0\implies x+y>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the definition of "$>$":

If $y > x$,
there is a $d > 0$
such that
$y = x+d$.

Then
$y^2-x^2
=(x+d)^2-x^2
=x^2+2xd+d^2-x^2
= 2xd+d^2
> 0
$
since both
$2xd$ and $d^2$
are positive.